# Returning a map from setIn -- ImmutableJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm trying to return a nested value inside setIn, the way I'm doing it now, is that I'm accessing my value I need, but I need to map it first. Immutable provides this, however, I need to use `Immutable.Map().map(..)` after my array. I get a returned value from my method, but it doesn't contain any values, of which it should. Anyone know another way to accomplish this? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an iterable to the Immutable.Map() constructor, otherwise you are creating an empty map.

It's hard to be precise without more details, but assuming that 'result' is an array of resources and you need an array of resource ids, than something like this should work.

```
let tempStateId = newState.setIn([populateKey, 'íds'], Immutable.Map(result).map(resource => resource.id))
```

Comment: newState is already an immutable object, so it should work fine as it is :)

Comment: Welcome :) Yeah, you don't need the Immutable.Map() `result.map(resource => resource.id)` as a second parameter should be enough